# Bind9 DNS reverse lookup fail with no reason

Tags: ubuntu, bind

Okay so I got a problem, that my reverse lookup fail on my bind9 dns

```
# nslookup 192.168.1.6

Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find 6.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

# nano /var/named/6.zone
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA localhost (
991079290 ; serial
28800 ; refresh
 14400 ; retry
 3600000 ; expire
 86400 ; default_ttl
 )
 IN NS localhost.
 6.1 IN PTR localhost. ; 192.168.1.6

# nano /etc/bind/named.conf.local
zone “6.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa” {
type master;
file “/var/named/6.zone”
    allow-update {key rndc-key; };

};
 # /etc/bind/named.conf

 include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
 include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
 include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

as I see it, everything looks fine. what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The config you have provided is providing a PTR record for `6.1.6.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa`.  You either want to modify the `zone` statement (remove the `6.1` at the beginning), or the relative name in the zone file (try `@` instead of `6.1`).